# SimpleITK with C# displaying image stops program execution

Tags: c#, imagej, itk

I am using SimpleITK library with C# for MRI image processing.
I want to display preprocessed images at various stages of my program execution.
To display image I use the following code

```
SimpleITK.Show(image);
```

It looks like the execution process stops after showing the image with ImageJ. I would like to display consecutive images in a single run one after another.

The system SITK_SHOW_COMMAND variable is set to %a %f

I am running my code on Windows 10

Is this a bug related to SimpleITK Show function or it is something set wrong in my environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the Show function.  The wait time after launching ImageJ was set to 500 seconds.  That's because the units are different than on Linux/OS X.  They're seconds instead of milliseconds.

I've submitted a bug fix to SimpleITK that changes the wait time on Windows to 1 second.  This should show up the master branch of the source code in the next day or two.  So if you can build SimpleITK for yourself, you can get a new version soon.

If not, you'll have to wait for the next release of SimpleITK.  I don't know when that will be, though.